# Are there any way to update the variable value in Flask?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jinja2

What I try to do is when I click the button, it shall do the ajax post function to python and get back some new variable that contains the content that I want to replace the previous content.

This is my route.py.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    table_content = ['jack', 'micheal']
    return render_template('index.html',table_content=table_content)


@app.route('/update_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_data():

    table_content = ['john', 'owen', 'bern']

    return jsonify(table_content=table_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Ajax -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="mytable">
        {% for content in table_content %}
            <tr>
                <h4>{{ content }}</h4>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button onclick="refresh()">Click</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        function refresh(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "/update_data",
                type: "POST", 
                data:'hello'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#mytable').load(document.URL +  ' #mytable');

        });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Step 1 : I have the base content in `main()` function and display it in template normally.

Step 2 : Do some action in template (click button) and then do ajax post to the python `update_data()` function.

Step 3 : 'update_data()' send back some new variable for update the old variable data.

Comment: is there a question here? is it not working? how is it not working? what would you expect the behaviour to be, versus what is it doing now? why is this tagged [java]?

Comment: @Joran Beasley thank you for response, i want it to update `table_content` variable in template after i click the button and do `update_data` function but it not working in my code.

Comment: What error do you see in the console? Do .fail() to check what the error is